# Get field value from item in SPListItemCollection

Tags: caml-query, caml

I am confused with `SPQuery`. How can I use it to get listitem values. Let's say I have a list "Cinema" with 20 columns but i only want 4.

- Film ID
- Film Name
- Film Type
- Film Review

How can i get all list items using SPQuery and access them using SPListItemCollection.

Example. not working

```
spsite site = new site("portal.filmworld.com/abc")
spweb web = site.openweb();
{
   splist li = web.lists["Films"];
   spquery q = new spquery();
   q.query = string.Format("<FieldRef Name='FilmID' /><FieldRef Name='FilmName' /><FieldRef Name='FilmType' /><FieldRef Name='FilmReview' />");

   splistitemcollection items = li.getitems(q);

   foreach(SPListItem item in items)
   {
          string name = item.filmName;     <----   it's not working gives exception of null
   }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
   splist li = web.lists["Films"];
   spquery q = new spquery();
   q.Query=""; //Enter a caml query here if you would like to restrict your results...
   q.ViewFields = string.Concat(
                                   "<FieldRef Name='FilmID' />",
                                   "<FieldRef Name='FilmName' />",
                                   "<FieldRef Name='FilmType' />",
                                   "<FieldRef Name='FilmReview' />");
   q.ViewFieldsOnly = true; // Fetch only the data that we need

   splistitemcollection items = li.getitems(q);

   foreach(SPListItem item in items)
   {
         string name = item["FilmName"].toString();

   }
```

The query is for restricting the items that we want to return, not the data returned for each item.

Answer (score 2):

You do as you always do with ListItems. For example:

```
string name = item["filmName"].toString();
```

For not nullable types (like DateTime) you should do a null check:

```
DateTime aDate = item["myDateColumn"] != null ? DateTime.parse(item["myDateColumn"].toString()) : null;
```

(OK, I know there exists better ways but this is pretty generic)

So, basically not so hard :)

Comment: did my query synatx ok ? as i am not sure if it is

Comment: i want all list items and only above columns when there are 20 columns in list

Comment: The you should use the ViewFields property and not the Query. Like q.ViewFields = "what you wrote as q.Query"

Comment: plz give some explample i am new to caml query

Comment: I did, just change your q.Query to q.ViewFields

Answer (score 2):

The way you wrote q.query is not the usual way to write the query.   A normal query would be where you add your conditions in CAML syntax so that you return a subset of the items based on your criteris; if you are looking to get back all the items from a list, then you don't need SPQuery.  Here is an example of an SPQuery:

```
q.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FilmID'/><Value>Some random film id</Value></Eq></Where>"
```

Here is a tutorial: [SPQuery in SharePoint 2010](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/07/18/spquery-in-sharepoint-2010-tutorial/)

The other thing is you wouldn't access the field FilmName like you did above, UNLESS you used something like Linq to SharePoint/Entity Framework (which is a totally separate discussion!).  Try using item["FilmName"] instead.   Here is another tutorial: [Sharepoint 2010 – How best to reference a Column (Field) from an SPListItem](http://www.myfriedmind.com/2011/07/sharepoint-2010-how-best-to-reference-a-column-field-from-an-splistitem/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: if you are looking to get back all the items from a list, then you don't need SPQuery   ,,,then   what do i need ?

Comment: It would be something like the following:

SPList list = web.Lists["Some List"];
SPListItemCollection items = list.Items;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.items.aspx

Comment: which following /

Comment: `SPList li = web.Lists["Film"];  SPListItemCollection items= li.Items;`

[MSDN: SPList.Items Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.items.aspx)

Comment: I still think he is better of with the SPQuery since he does not want all fields. The data loaded is minimized with the query